# How to extract integer values from an object using java in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I executed a script to get screen coordinates from map coordinates in selenium webdriver using java and java script. I got the screen coordinates and store the coordinates to a variable of type Object. The code I executed for getting the screen coordinates is given below

```
Object screenxy = executor.executeScript(js1);
```

After executing the above mentioned code I got screenxy = {x=2428, y=21324}. How can I seperate x and y as integers.
If anyone know the solution please help me

Comment: Casting to a Point and using getX() getY() should work- https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Point.html

Comment: While casting to a Point I got an exception .Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.Point. The code is given ```Point p = (Point) screenxy;```

Comment: @Grasshopper Can you help me to cast coordinates to type Point?

Comment: I was wrong it cannot be cast to a Point. U need to cast to Map<String,Object>. Please refer to this. - https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5154#issuecomment-192107247